# When should I use "If there is/are"?

Tags: usage, singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

I've heard that the phrase "If there is/are" can be used in the sentences. But I don't know exactly how to use in sentences. Although I don't know its exact usage, I've tried to use it in the sentences below:

1. If there is a quite a silence at the market, there must be something wrong.
2. If there is a private discussion at their home right now, we don't need to go there.
3. If there are many fishes at that pond, let's move for haunting.
4. If there are similarities between their meanings, you need to be more specific when you differentiate them.
5. If there is a mistake in my writing, please correct it for me.

Could you please tell me the correct usage of "If there is/are?"

Comment: The question is surprising to me, considering that you seem to know how to use *If* and know the meaning of each of *there be/is/are/was/were/has/have/had been/can/could/will/would/shall/should/may/might/ought to/must/etc. be/have been*.

Comment: You seem to have a good grasp on "if there is/are", although your 3rd sentence doesn't make much sense to me as a whole... (and "fish" can be the plural of "fish", and would be preferable to "fishes" in that sentence)